# Query regarding Full outer join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, full-outer-join

I have two tables and joining them using full outer join.

Tab1:

| Crossswalk | Ind | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Y | abc |

Tab2:

| Crosswalk | Ind | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Null | abc |
| 123 | Null | bcd |

```
select coalesce(a.crosswalk,b.crosswalk), a.Ind, coalesce(a.name,b.name)
from Tab1 a
full join Tab2 b on a.crosswalk = b.crosswalk and a.name = b.name
```

I am getting result as

| Crosswalk | Ind | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Y | abc |
| 123 | Null | bcd |

I want indicator field to populated with Y for both the rows as below.

| Crosswalk | Ind | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Y | abc |
| 123 | Y | bcd |

this is a sample record. I have more records and Ind field should always populated with the Ind value from Tab1

Comment: Table schema and sample data please

Comment: Is the crosswalk unique in Tab1? For instance: what if there is a row 123, N, XYZ in tab1? In that case what will come up in your result for Ind? X or Y??

Comment: its always unique inTab1. Each crosswalk will have one value only either N or Y

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it looks like you need to show cross_walk and Ind from Tab1 and name from Tab2.

```
select a.crosswalk, a.Ind , b.name
from Tab1 a  join Tab2 b on a.crosswalk=b.crosswalk
```

Here is the DB Fiddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0145f950c2bfef3af7b983a229fc387d